# Using VBA to count amount of employees in a location, some employees are duplicated

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet like this:

| Employee | Location | Status | Resigned? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Employee1 | place1 |  | 31/12/9999 |
| Employee1 | place1 | leave | 31/12/9999 |
| Employee1 | place1 |  | 12/05/2023 |
| Employee2 | place1 | leave | 16/05/2023 |
| Employee3 | place1 |  | 31/12/9999 |
| Employee3 | place1 | leave | 31/12/9999 |
| Employee4 | place1 |  | 31/12/9999 |
| Employee5 | place1 |  | 31/12/9999 |
| Employee6 | place2 | leave | 31/12/9999 |
| Employee7 | place2 | leave | 31/12/9999 |

I would like to count all the employees per location (ignoring duplicates) and who are still employed at the end of the current month (May in this case)

I found a formula to help:
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$1:B1;B1)>1;0;COUNTIFS($B$1:B1;B1)) on the Input sheet which counts only unique values when dragged down and then used =SUMIF(Input!C:C;E2;Input!L:L) on the output sheet where I only have location I can get the approximate employee numbers.

I cannot find a way to ignore employee if he has a resignation date before end of the month and in VBA I could not find a way to count only the unique values and add them to the sheet of locations.

I have a sheet with about 7300 rows to read from into the sheet with the locations.

Comment: Is `12/05/9999` on purpose or should that be `12/05/2023`

Comment: Should Employees 1 & 3 have that they left on the 31/12/9999 and were also active on 31/12/9999?

Comment: *in VBA I could not find a way to count only the unique values* Use a [Dictionary](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)

Comment: Why 9999? That seems odd

Answer (score 0):

you can use this formula to List all the employees in Location "Place1"  who are still employed at the end of the current month

```
=UNIQUE(IFERROR(LET(list,(Location="place1")*(Status<>"leave")*(Resigned>EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))* SEQUENCE(10),INDEX(Employee,LARGE(IF(list>0,list,""),SEQUENCE(10)))),""))
```

then you can count them.

Comment: I found the answer in using Dictionairy functions. Thanks to –@Foxfire And Burns And Burns